# Deserialization of JSON to create the POJO and the related reference

Tags: java, json, oracle-apex, pojo

I'm trying to create a POJO with a relation to another POJO with the Oracle APEX ORDS RESTful API.

#### The context

Let me start with explaining the context I have to deal with.

Consider the following POJO's:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Brand {
    private Pencil[] pencils;
    // standard getters and setters
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Pencil {
    private int length;
    private Brand brand;
    private Color color;
    // standard getters and setters
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Color {
    private int red;
    private int green;
    private int blue;
    // standard getters and setters
}
```

The database structure in APEX looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Brand (
    id int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE Pencil (
    id int NOT NULL,
    length int NOT NULL,
    brand_id int NOT NULL,
    color_id int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (brand_id) REFERENCES Brand(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (color_id) REFERENCES Color(id)
);
CREATE TABLE Color (
    id int NOT NULL,
    red int NOT NULL,
    green int NOT NULL,
    blue int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The ORDS URI template is `../brand/{brand_ID}/pencils` and uses the following get request handler source with the source type "Query":

```
SELECT p.length, c.red, c.green, c.blue FROM pencil p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN color c ON c.id = p.color_id
        WHERE p.brand_id = :brand_ID
```

A request could return something like the following JSON:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "length": 100,
            "red": 150,
            "green": 200,
            "blue": 250,
        },
        {
            "length": 50,
            "red": 100,
            "green": 150,
            "blue": 200,
        }
    ],
    "first:" {
        "$ref": "..."
    }
}
```

#### The question

While reading this JSON on the client side where the POJO's are created I ran into a problem. I'm able to get the length property of the Pencil instances set to the correct value. However the color property of the Pencil instance will remain `null`. I guess it is because the JSON properties red, green and blue are unknown to Pencil and thus ignored. If I'm correct about that then I might have two solutions but for none of those I know how to achieve them.

#### A few possible solutions

1. Target the properties of the Color class through annotations and stop ignoring them, declare where they could be used for.
2. Somehow add a JSON object to each array item in the response with the key `color` and the properties of the Color class.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few things that you could try.

1. You can modify the json response object to match with your data modeling POJOs.
2. if you can't modify the json response to match your client side data modeling, you can create a JsonDto which matches with the json response and then just construct your POJOs manually using the JsonDto as necessary.

Hope this helps. :)